# Using the plot function in R, I want my data points with labels to be spread out instead of indexed since I only have y values

Tags: r, function, plot

I'm having trouble visualizing the spread of my data. I want to remove some variability before starting an experiment therefore I need to get rid of the largest and smallest observations. I'm using the plot function with labels so I can figure out which points are causing this variability.

I'm using the code:

```
plot(length, 
main= "longest leaf", ylab= "longest leaf (cm)", col= "blue", pch = 19)
text(length, labels=name, cex= 0.7)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqTNo.jpg)
and for some reason my plot has an X axis with "index" and the values are concentrated in a regression line. I'd rather the points be pulled apart so I can actually see the labels.

Please help!

Attached is a picture of the graph

Comment: You might consider using the `identify` function instead of labeling everything